# Clustering markers on mapbox / leaflet

Tags: javascript, json, leaflet, geojson, mapbox

I'm trying to set up a clustered map on mapbox, like http://leaflet.github.io/Leaflet.markercluster/example/marker-clustering-realworld.388.html

But their example uses a plain .js file as data
http://www.mapbox.com/mapbox.js/assets/realworld.388.js

And the only thing I can get from mapbox is .geojson
http://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/thebteam.map-w9jzcznw/markers.geojson

Is there a way I can convert the geojson to js (on a regular basis)? Or export a javascript array from mapbox?

EDIT: ended up switching my data to CSV and finding a parser. Here's the code that worked, if anyone needs it:

```
var url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?key=abc123';

$.get(url, function(data) {
  var addressPoints = $.csv.toArrays(data);
  var map = L.mapbox.map('map', 'map-abc123').setView([20.30, 18.98], 2);
  var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup({ showCoverageOnHover: false });

  for (var i = 0; i < addressPoints.length; i++) {
    var a = addressPoints[i];
    var title = a[2];
    var marker = L.marker(new L.LatLng(a[0], a[1]), {
      icon: L.mapbox.marker.icon({'marker-size': 'small', 'marker-color': 'e8168c'}),
      title: title
    });
    marker.bindPopup(title);
    markers.addLayer(marker);
  }

  map.addLayer(markers);

});
```

Comment: Why don't jsut write a loop to do the work for you?

Comment: My JS skills are not so great.

Comment: Ended up switching my data to CSV and finding a parser.

Comment: Do you think it would be possible to take the csv from a local file? something like  var url = 'file://c:/output.csv' ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var geojson = dataFromMapbox;
var lat;
var lng;
for(var i= 0;i<geojson.features.length;i++)
  {
    lat = geojson.features[i].geometry.coordinates[0];
    lng = geojson.features[i].geometry.coordinates[1];

    //create a marker with those values, pass it to a MarkerCluster object

  }
```

Comment: This is smart. I ended up switching my data to CSV, but this looks like it would do the same thing I tried.

Answer (score 9):

Create a geoJson layer and then add that layer to MarkerCluster:

```
 var markers = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
 var geoJsonFeature =  = {
  "type": "Feature",
  "properties": {
    "name": "Coors Field",
    "amenity": "Baseball Stadium",
    "popupContent": "This is where the Rockies play!"
  },
  "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [-104.99404, 39.75621]
  }
 };
 var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geoJsonFeature);

 markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);
 map.addLayer(markers);
```

Comment: What is "dataFromMapbox", and what does it look like?

Comment: dataFromMapbox is the geoJson itself, sorry if it wasnt clear i copied the fragmen of my own code. I edited the code so it is more readable