# Clustering markers from csv with leaflet and omnivore

Tags: javascript, csv, leaflet, cluster-computing

I'm trying to cluster data from csv parsed with omnivore and with the markercluster plugin but nothing happens. When i'm not using the plugin, I can see all my markers so...

I saw many examples [like this](http://bl.ocks.org/wboykinm/9374994) but they all use mapbox and I build a pure leaflet map. I've also [tried this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17005784/clustering-markers-on-mapbox-leaflet?rq=1) but my problem is still here.

All I have in my console is a "syntax error" for my csv but it's not the core problem.

My csv looks like this :

```
date,dcomiris,latitude,longitude,infra,iris,com,name
2014-01-01,600570101,49.4295880722704,2.08997269112341,7871F,Cathedrale-Universite,60057,Beauvais
```

My code looks like this for now :

```
var map = L.map('map').fitBounds([[49.072667, 1.653442],[49.737499, 3.158569]]);

L.tileLayer('http://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a>'
}).addTo(map);

var points = omnivore.csv('my.csv');
// points.addTo(map);

var markers = new L.markerClusterGroup({showCoverageOnHover:false});
markers.addLayer(points);
map.addLayer(markers);
```

What did I miss?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The key step is the `.on('ready', callback)` from the [cited tutorial](http://bl.ocks.org/wboykinm/9374994).

Leaflet-omnivore accesses asynchronously your CSV file, so your `points` variable is still empty at the time you add it into `markers` cluster group.

```js
var points = omnivore.csv('my.csv');
//points.addTo(map);

var markers = L.markerClusterGroup({
  showCoverageOnHover: false
});

map.addLayer(markers);

points.on('ready', function () {
  console.log(points.getLayers().length)
  markers.addLayer(points);
});
```

Demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/UJfvxQmT3OnGxFw4DtCd?p=preview

Comment: I was thinking that the `.on('ready, callback)` was only use in mapbox. I met a problem with it before.

Comment: Yes it is common in mapbox specific extension of Leaflet, and here it is available as well, without needing the rest of mapbox.